# Visual Studio Team Services / SonarQube: Converting a .trx/.coverage file to a LCOV?

Tags: javascript, msbuild, sonarqube, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm trying to convert the .coverage or the .trx file generated from running a Test Assemblies task in Team Services (was VSO) build manager into a LCOV file that's parseable by SonarQube so that javascript coverage results are reported.

Is there any preset/recommended way to do this? I figure I could just use a powershell script to call Chutzpah (as it's included as a nuget package) and convert the .trx to an LCOV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) is an open source JavaScript test runner which enables you to run unit tests using QUnit, Jasmine, Mocha, CoffeeScript and TypeScript.

You can use the [transforms setting](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Transforms-Setting) to specify which output transformers should run after testing is finished. Output test coverage data as LCOV file to C:\temp\lcov.dat:

```
{
    "Transforms": [
        { "Name": "lcov", "Path": "lcov.dat" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Cece,

I'm currently importing Chutzpah into the source files with Nuget and then using this guide: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/.

Comment: I think that it's still running VSTests.Console.Exe with the test adapters found within the package directory. 

Is there a way I can pass in a parameter through VSTests.Console.Exe to the Chutzpah adapter to format the output as a LCOV.dat file (I read that to do this, "/lcov filename" needs to be passed to the Chutzpah console runner).

Comment: Do you use hosted build agent or local build agent? Have you specify the "Path to the custom test adaptor"? The Chutzpah settings file is an .json file that you can place anywhere in your testing directories to inform Chutzpah of test specific settings: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File

Comment: I'm using a hosted build agent and I have specified the path. Will the settings file still work in this case?

Comment: After modifying the settings file I found in our test directories and adding the transforms field, the LCOV gets generated. Now to get the coverage to display in SQ...